# automatic population of date based on when a check box in another cell is clicked in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two columns (fields) in my google sheet. The first column is a check box, the second column is a date type. What I want is , as soon as I click (check) the checkbox in the first column, the second column value should be auto-populated with the current date -- so that I can track when the checkbox was checked.

[image]

Comment: added screenshot for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need a script like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if (activeSheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {                    // SHEET NAME
var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn();
if (col == 1) {                                             // COLUMN WITH CHECKBOX
var dateCell = aCell.offset(0,1);                           // DATE OFFSET ROWS / COLUMNS
if (aCell.getValue() === true) {
var newDate = new Date();
dateCell.setValue(newDate);
} else {
dateCell.setValue("");
}}}}
```